# Tags searching and completion

Tags: completion, search, ctags

I've tried to create a tags table for my assembler project using:

`etags --language=none --regex="/[ \t]*\.\([^: \t]+\)/\1/i" *.asm`

Which does work to a degree, and indeed when I load the `TAGS` file into Emacs, I see all the tags created just fine (from assembly labels).

My problem arises when I try and use `M-.` to search for a specific tag. It only shows me a very small subset of the tags in the `*completions*` buffer, despite all the tags seemingly present in the `TAGS` file.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to match:

```
.t0 DCB 0
.t1 DCB 0
.t2 DCB 0
.t4 DCB 0
```

Yet when I do `M-.`, only the `t0` tag will be listed in `*completions*`. If I manually enter `t1` it can jump straight to it!

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? Are you using the `etags` program that comes with that version?

Comment: 24.5.1, and yeah, using the `etags` program that comes with it :(

Comment: I have no idea about results for asm code, but in general be aware that Exuberant Ctags is a thing that exists, and (like GNU ctags) it produces Emacs-compatible TAGS files when given a `-e` flag. In some cases Exuberant Ctags gives significantly better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you. I've reproduced it in the current master and pushed a fix: [770db45d6769](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=770db45d6769134aa3a853e2ff38089a1e8a3327).

If you don't build Emacs from Git, you can try applying this patch to your currently installed version.